# Custom Rendering Extensions in cloud Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database

We want to have scalable Reporting services. And we need to install Custom Rendering Extensions on this scalable Reporting Services. This is the main requirement for us. SQL Azure Reporting doesn't suite the requirements, because it is impossible to extend this service with custom rendering extension. We had an idea to install Reporting Services on each instance separated from SQL Azure and Azure Reporting, but Rendering Extensibility is not available in free editions of SQL Server and it costs too much to use paid edition. The database of these reporting services instances will be stored in SQL Azure and we will be able to leverage scalable Reporting Services tool with the required rendering extension. The problem is price, complexity and no benefits from SQL Azure Reporting. So, we got stuck with Microsoft clouds. And don't see any reasonable solution with Microsoft clouds.

So we considered Reporting Services on EC2 as they have special cloud license. And we are not quite sure whether it is possible to achieve what we need or not.
We've found that it's possible to install SQL Server2008R2 on EC2 so that the data of the database will be stored in EBS which is available to all the instances. So we have scalable Reporting Services in that case.
The question is lying in the Amazon Virtual Images:
We suppose that we need to install predefined configuration with Windows OS and SQL Server 2008R2 and we wonder if it (1) includes Reporting Services, (2)is it possible to install some more software on this predefined virtual machine (rendering extension), (3)is it possible to organize such scalable Reporting Services with Custom Rendering extensions and to leverage load balancing and etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the AWS provided SQL Server 2008 R2 AMI if you don't want to.

If you bring your own licenses, you could go with a base EC2 install, and then install whatever software you want over the top of it.

ie - install the Windows AMI, and then run the SQL Server installation of your choice.  The second step then is to install any additional extensions you require.

I would also recommend that once you complete the installation that you create an AMI of it so that you can repeat the installation at a later date.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! This is exactly what I wanted to know.